# JanusGraph edges to non-existent vertices

Tags: cassandra, duplicates, gremlin, janusgraph

We are using ***JanusGraph 0.2.0*** with ***Apache Cassandra 3.0.9*** as the backend, we have upgraded our graph from Titan 1.0.0. Recently we have started seeing too many edges to non-existant vertices. The JanusGraph documentation talks about such [issues](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/eventual-consistency.html#_temporary_inconsistency) and says it's a temporary issue, however in our case we are seeing such cases persist for days and not resolved automatically until we remove this edge manually.
Following are some of the examples:

```
//following vertex has 5 outward edges.
gremlin> g.V().has('msid', 62999910).outE('hie_child')
```

> ==>e[k82hgjm-5wxsm4w-7a6tx-5quay20][12875591696-hie_child->12506931432]
>   ==>e[k82hhc2-5wxsm4w-7a6tx-5qub17s][12875591696-hie_child->12506935528]
>   ==>e[k82hg5e-5wxsm4w-7a6tx-6ahfuds][12875591696-hie_child->13694648464]
>   ==>e[k82hgxu-5wxsm4w-7a6tx-6ahtd2o][12875591696-hie_child->13695279216]
>   ==>e[k82hhqa-5wxsm4w-7a6tx-6ejuhts][12875591696-hie_child->13940555968]

```
//however 2 of these edges (first & third) are to non-existant vertices
gremlin>  g.V().has('msid', 62999910).outE('hie_child').inV().valueMap()
```

> **==>[]**
>
> ==>[createdAt:[1519129694836],msid:[63000004],insertedAt:[1519129696038],cmstype:[1010],trank:[8],msname:[6],mstype:[3],artupdatedAt:[1519129696038],type:[0],mssubtype:[0],expDate:[9223372036854775807],updatedAt:[1519129696038]]
>
> **==>[]**
>
> ==>[createdAt:[1519129694763],msid:[63000003],insertedAt:[1519129696038],cmstype:[1010],trank:[8],msname:[5],mstype:[3],artupdatedAt:[1519129696038],type:[0],mssubtype:[0],expDate:[9223372036854775807],updatedAt:[1519129696038]]
>
> ==>[createdAt:[1519129694870],msid:[62999944],insertedAt:[1519129696038],cmstype:[1010],trank:[8],msname:[P1-Hockey-IMG_6063],mstype:[3],artupdatedAt:[1519129696038],type:[0],mssubtype:[0],expDate:[9223372036854775807],updatedAt:[1519129696038]]

1. Is anyone else facing this issue, if yes is there any solution to stop JanusGraph having such edges at all?
2. Is there a way to detect all such edges and remove them?

Comment: What was the solution to your problem ?

Comment: Manually delete such ghost edges as and when they are detected.